# Поиск элемента и его замена, переход с jquery на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перехожу с jquery на js, заменяю постепенно в проекте код на нативный js, и тут получилась ошибка. Код на jQuery:

```
$('img.svg').each(function () {
  var $img = $(this);
  var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
  var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

  $.get(imgURL, function (data) {
    var $svg = $(data).find('svg');
    if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
      $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
    }
    $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
    $img.replaceWith($svg);

  }, 'xml');
});
```

Код на js:

```
let svg = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');
svg.forEach(element => {
  let img = element;
  let imgClass = img.getAttribute('class');
  let imgURL = img.getAttribute('src');
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', imgURL);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
    let svgi = data.querySelector('svg');
    if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
      svgi = svgi.setAttribute('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
    }
    svgi = svgi.removeAttribute('xmlns:a');
    img.replaceWith(svgi);
 }
 xhr.send();
})
```

Выдаёт ошибку "data.querySelector is not a function", хотелось бы понять как получить svg на js. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: перед `let svgi = data.querySelector('svg');` напишете `console.log(data)` и станет всё ясно

Comment: Вы пытаетесь селектором получить год из строки которая в data. Не верно.

Comment: Я понимаю, что не верно, хотелось бы узнать как правильно сделать

Comment: @VashkaStream похоже что data это просто строка, в которой нет определения для функции querySelector, по скольку она есть у ДОМ элементов можно инициализировать блок `let block = document.createElement("div")` и через `block.innerHTML = data` записать внутрь все содержимое `data` и вызвать `block.querySelector("svg")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* ... */
xhr.open('GET', imgURL);
xhr.responseType = 'document'; 
/* ... */
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

---

Чтение ответа предполагается из свойства `response`.
В данном случае, вероятно что оно будет содержать значение типа `SVGDocument`, а не `Document` (как было бы в случае html-файла).

Comment: В общем я настроил код, он работает, только теперь выдаёт ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange, вот код внутри обработчика let svgi = xhr.response.querySelector('svg');
      console.log(svgi)
      svgi.classList.add(imgClass);
      img.replaceWith(svgi);

Comment: @VashkaStream, по ссылке в ответе статья, там написано об этом: «Если сервер возвращает данные, которые не совместимы с установленным responseType, значение response будет null.» - видимо, получаемый с сервера файл не является валидным SVG (XML) документом...

Comment: Видимо вы не так поняли, код полностью отрабатывает, не смотря на ошибку

Comment: @VashkaStream, Полностью - невозможно: выполнение скрипта всегда прерывается неотловленными ошибками.

Comment: Я сам удивился конечно, но скрипт полностью отрабатывает, и не ломает следующий за ним js код